# AWS EB Deployment error: AppDeployEnactHook/03start-task.sh: Activity failed

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, docker-compose, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I've been trying to deploy a multi-container Docker environment to AWS Elastic Beanstalk in the simplest manner possible. I have uploaded the docker images which creates the containers that constitutes the docker-compose.yml to individual public Docker hub repositories (eg. *myusername/production_app, myusername/production_celery, myusername/postgres, myusername/production_client).

"docker-compose up" works successfully (no errors in docker-compose logs)

Next i create the below Dockerrun.aws.json based on my docker-compose.yml, created a new Elastic Beanstalk application and proceeded to upload this file when creating the webserver environment.

However, the application fails to deploy with the following error:

> XXXX/StartupStage1/AppDeployEnactHook/03start-task.sh] : Activity
>   failed.

**Dockerrun.aws.json**

```
{
 "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": 2,
 "containerDefinitions": [
    {
      "name": "app",
      "image": "myusername/production_app",
      "essential": true,
      "memoryReservation": 200,
      "portMappings": [
        {
          "hostPort": 5000,
          "containerPort": 5000
        }
    },
    {
      "name": "celery",
      "image": "myusername/production_celery",
      "essential": true,
      "memoryReservation": 200,
    },
     {
      "name": "client",
      "image": "myusername/production_client",
      "essential": true,
      "memoryReservation": 200,
       "portMappings": [
        {
          "hostPort": 3007,
          "containerPort": 3000
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "postgres",
      "image": "myusername/postgres",
      "essential": true,
      "memoryReservation": 200,
       "portMappings": [
        {
          "hostPort": 5432,
          "containerPort": 5432
        }
      ]
    }
 ]
}
```

Comment: Do you have any extra log besides that? I´m not seing any authentication section for Docker hub over there. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/private-auth.html

Comment: Any luck on this? I am erroring out at the same place...